# How to work with a cloned git repository locally?

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

I am new to Git and have done some rudimentary tutorials on how to clone, add, commit stuff.

I recently git cloned an online repository on my local DEV environment with something like:

```
git clone git@something.beanstalkapp.com:/somefile.git
```

In order to make changes to the code and then be able to stage and commit those changes, what do I first? Do I need to add the local repository?

Can someone show me a small example: like git add "blah blah". git commit -m "this is my first commit to remote repository" etc etc

Sorry I know I am not doing a good job explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you cloned, you probably have a folder `somefile` created at the pwd. cd into that.

Here you can add files and do commit, for example:

```
touch README
git add README
git commit -m "Adding a README"
```

After this, you can push the changes back to the repo that you cloned from:

```
git push origin master
```

Please also lookup some git tutorials on getting started - http://schacon.github.com/git/gittutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

Some useful resources to get you started:

- [Starting with Git: Cheat Sheet](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/starting-with-git-cheat-sheet/)
- [Git For Windows Developers – Git Series](http://lostechies.com/jasonmeridth/2009/06/01/git-for-windows-developers-git-series-part-1/)
- [Git Submodules: Adding, Using, Removing, Updating](http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/)
- [Pro Git Book](http://progit.org/book/)

Answer (score 1):

To make the remote repository aware of your changes you need to "push", as in

```
git push origin master
```

Here is a small [howto](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html)